# Many posts by the same user, no question, cites own papers

Tags: discussion

The user tianren cheng has posted spates of "questions" which purport to announce results (no question asked), and cite papers in http://vixra.org. Latest example I came across is [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342652/a-new-method-to-calcular-the-included-angle-by-studying-the-circle-norms). I'm not qualified to review the cited work, but there is no question (and the posts were flagged as such), so I voted to close them. All the posts have the same general structure, announce some result, and link to a paper. It is starting to get annoying...

What should be done in such a case? I can understand a slipup or two, but this is more of a landslide.

Comment: It turns out that you [were not the first to notice](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/67972/tianren-cheng). But in general, the best thing you can do is flag for moderator attention.

Comment: @mixedmath, I searched here for that case to add my comments, came up empty. So I should have looked at the account. Noted for future reference. Thanks!

Comment: Should we be _naming names_ in this instance?  It seems that the current case has been dealt with, and the offense was not (IMO) sufficiently egregious to warrant any prolonged discussion.  There does seem to be a general question (_What should we do if a single user rapidly posts several non-questions?_) that can — even should — be dealt with in a generic manner.  (I guess I should notify @mixedmath as well.)

Comment: Well that was a long list of delete votes... I hope that others will soon join me. On MO we simply flag these as spam and get it over with quicker. Alas, that is not the MSE way.

Comment: @JasperLoy, s*t, should have waited to be the _last_ one to vote closure on that $%@#&... Oh, well. There _will_ be others...

Comment: The same person was [quite active on mathoverflow](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1296/#Item_22) over the past week.